# Updating preloaded sqlite database without losing user data in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have done a few searches and read a number of posts but I am still not successful trying to update a database without losing the data that is already saved.

I created the DB using this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

In the new database I want to migrate data from a main table to a new table that will store the user's favourites. Currently, they are stored in the main table. In the onupgrade function I tried renaming the table and inserting the record into the new table. That didn't work. I also tried saving the data to a cursor and then populating the new table but that didn't work. For these methods, I got errors saying that the new/old table cannot be found.

Below is the onUpgrade() function.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE books rename to old_books");


        try {
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }


    db.execSQL("INSERT into favourites (_id, type, title, notes,rating)   SELECT _id ,type, title, notes, rating FROM old_books where rating > 0;");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old_books;");
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to update the database without losing data using the implementation from the tutorial? All I need to do is copy the favourites from the "books" table and load them to the "favourites" table when users update the app.

Comment: What is the `copyDataBase()` call supposed to do?

Comment: @CL. copyDatabase() copies the DB from the APK to the device. The cose is below. `private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }`

Comment: And why are you doing this in the middle of `onUpgrade`?

Comment: Admittedly, I saw that approach in a number of tutorials. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`onUpgrade` is called while the database is open and a transaction is active.
You cannot overwrite the database file at this time (and this would lose all the data in the old file).

Just remove the `copyDataBase()` call.

Comment: Where would I do the overwrite?

Comment: You would not do any overwrite at all. You upgrade the database with the SQL commands.

Comment: Can you show how I would code that? I've been trying various attempts but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your existing SQL commands are perfectly fine, except that you forgot to create the `favourites` table.

Comment: Would I still need to create the favourites table given that I have already created it in the preloaded database file. In the new database file I've updated various rows and also added an index to the main table. So I want to make updates to the main table but I need to preserve the favourites that the user has entered.

Comment: There is no better mechanism. Preloading and dynamic updates exclude each other.

Comment: So creating the new table dynamically will resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQLite browser to get preloaded database so you can update the database file then change it's version not create a new database file and keep the data ! [Source tutorial](http://androidgifts.com/import-sqlite-database-into-android-using-sqlite-browser/) .... in my opinion this tutorial is better and more detailed than the one you refereed.